# How to rotate parent without affecting the children's location in blender?

Tags: transforms, parent, transform-orientation

Target:
Rotate Parent and Child without affecting Child's Location

Tried:

Parent A

- Child A
- Child A

When rotating Parent A. Child A and Child B also rotates with the parent object as pivot point (as expected).
But how to make the child objects A and B rotate in their individual origins.

Also tried locking the location for  child A and B, but still when parent's rotation changes, child objects location also changes according to the parent change in rotation.

Comment: Don't parent the objects at all when you don't want them to move their position. Use a _Copy Rotation_ constraint.

Comment: Yeah, that should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to copy the rotation of the parent object without affecting anything else on the children, you shouldn't parent them at all in the first place. Just use *Copy Rotation* constraints on the objects that should inherit the rotation and set the one you rotate as *Target*:

[image: copy rotation constraint]